# Setting vim session name same as vim servername from vimrc

Tags: session, vim, server-name

Basically what I'm trying to achieve is set my vim-session name same as my vim servername from vimrc, i.e.

I'm using vim-session plugin and it provides an option to set the name of the autosave session by setting `g:session_autosave_to` in my vimrc, what I'm trying to achieve now is something like `let g:session_autosave_to=v:servername`

Don't know that's the right way to do, but I believe that should have worked and my session name should have been set to my servername, but that does not seem to be happen.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You might be able to access `$HOST` from vim. Or you could shell out to expand `!hostname`.

Comment: It seems the .vimrc is sourced even before the `v:servername` variable is defined hence I get the value as empty string. So for now as suggested I export the servername to a variable and use it in .vimrc. Though, I'm still now convinced with the way I'm doing it now. Will keep digging to fine a nice way around.